# Lower-case input and remove symbols in 1 function with Haskell

Tags: string, function, haskell, functional-programming, io

I'm so proud of myself! ^_^

I can finally write Haskell functions that work!

```
:: [String] -> [String]
lowerCase = nub.map (map toLower)
returnLowers = nub.map (filter isLower)
```

After the user's input is split into a list using the *words* function, my *lowerCase* function lower-cases the user's input (this will make it easier for the word / pattern matching that I want to do later in the program), and my *returnLowers* function filters and returns only the lower-case letters to remove any symbols, numbers, etc.

But I noticed both of these functions use *nub.map*, and I was wondering if there was a way I could combine these 2 functions into 1 super function to remove redundancy from the code.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: `nub.map` doesn't typecheck. Your first function is in fact `(nub . (map (map toLower)))`. Are you sure you know what `nub` does?

Comment: I know what nub is. It's a type of equality function that I "composed" to the map function. I was just wondering if there was a nicer / more "Haskelly" way of doing what I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define

```
nubMap f = nub . map f
```

and then

```
lowerCase = nubMap (map toLower)
returnLowers = nubMap (filter isLower)
```

but I don't see any advantage; what you have now looks fine. The duplication is minimal, and partially illusory: both functions don't actually use `nub.map`, they use `nub . map f` for some `f`. This might seem like a pedantic point, but you can't define `foo = nub.map` and then define both functions with it (it's actually a type error). In particular, `nub.map f` is actually `nub . (map f)`, not `(nub . map) f`.

Comment: I thought there might have been a more professional way of doing these functions with a list comprehension or something. But if the approach I took doesn't offend anyone, and is considered okay, it's okay with me as well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The point-free style you used is generally considered more idiomatic than list comprehensions, actually. The only suggestion I have would be to add spaces around the `.`.